# FMX Styles are not applied

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

Using Delphi 10.4 Version 27.0.40680.4203 (Sidney), I edited the default style for TButtons, TLabels, and TEdit boxes. My form at design time looks like this:

[image]

When I compile and run the application (Target Platform: Windows 32-bit) on Windows 10/64-bit, I get this:

[image: run-time form]

That is, button and label styles are applied, but the edit boxes have all but disappeared - the style seems to not have been applied.

Reloading the project or restarting Delphi/RAD Studio makes no difference. I saved the style sheet to a `.style` file and reloaded it into a new Stylebook - no joy.

Any ideas why it shows up correctly at design time but not at run-time, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Please provide the steps to reproduce. We need the content of the `.style` file, the `.fmx` file and the `.pas` file.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the styles for the correct platform? I experienced similar problem a while ago when trying to apply styles for Android application. To me everything looked just fine in Delphi IDE but no styles were applied in Android application. I later found out that I was editing the style that is to be used on Windows platform and not the style that is to be used on Android platform.

Comment: Hi, don't you have created a windows view , in that case maybe this form view overwrite the default dfm values